# Userpoints: Require userpoint for being able to create a node?

Tags: forms, userpoints

How would one go about requiring the user to have userpoints before creating a node?

Perhaps with some kind of Rules validation?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a module in the userpoints_contrib project, which does exactly this.

You can combine it with userpoints_nc or a rule to also deduct points when a node is created, so that creating nodes costs something.

Comment: Read through the module, I think this can be easily handled with Rules, there is an "After saving new node" event. :)

Comment: Yes, the basic task is easy to reproduce with a rule. userpoints_nc is however also able to deal with node deletions, revisions, author changes and so on (all optional/configurable), which is something you might or might not need... but if needed, would be a lot harder to correctly reproduce with rules.